# Make loop run only when holding right click

Tags: python, windows, mouse, pywin32, pyautogui

I'm trying to make a program that randomly moves the mouse only when the right mouse button is held to prank a friend.

I found some code online to detect right-clicks with Win32 API. When I added my own `while` loop, it didn't stop after it started. I tried adding an `if` statement with `break` but nothing changed.

```
import win32api
import pyautogui
import random

state = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)  # Right button down = 1. Button up = -128

while True:
    pressed = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)

    if pressed != state:  # Button state changed
        state = pressed
        print(pressed)

        if pressed < 0:
            print('Right Button Pressed')

            while pressed < 0: # If the right mouse button is pressed, move the mouse randomly.
                pyautogui.moveRel(random.randint(-10, 10), random.randint(-10, 10))
                if (pressed > 0):
                    break
        else:
            print('Right Button Released')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try replacing your main `while` loop with this one that uses the assignment (walrus) operator `:=` to continuously check the button state

```
has_right_clicked = False  # flag if the button has been pressed yet

while state := win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)  # Right button down = 1. Button up = -128:
    if state == 1:   # If the right mouse button is pressed, move the mouse randomly.
        has_right_clicked = True  # user has right-clicked, set the flag
        pyautogui.moveRel(random.randint(-10, 10), random.randint(-10, 10))
        
    if has_right_clicked:  # this will be ignored until the flag is set
        break  # if the user lets go of the button
```

The loop will start automatically because both `1` and `128` evaluate to `True`, which is why we need the extra `has_right_clicked` flag to break the loop! The caveat here, however, is that this loop will only run once. You should probably wrap this in a function that's bound to right-click so it can be called whenever the user right-clicks the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for input with `GetKeyState` is never the correct solution for anything.

To capture global mouse events you should probably use a [low-level mouse hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) in this case. I don't know if it is possible in Python but I assume there is a way...